# Invoke fingerprint touch on emulator from code by shell

Tags: android, shell

I am trying to make integration tests which test Fingerprint.

According to [google doc](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html) to invoke finger touch on emulator from terminal you need to use:

> adb -e emu finger touch < finger_id >

And this works for me. In my case id is 45146572. However in test you cannot input this command on your own as it should be done automatically.

I've been trying various things to make a workaround (eg. trying to understand how app is receiving information from sensor - maybe by some kind of broadcast intent etc.) and for now I still don't know how to do it.

I know that UiAutomation and UiAutomator's class - UiDevice has method

> [executeShellCommand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation.html#executeShellCommand(java.lang.String))

and I think that this might be helpful. But even if I do something like:

```
getUiDevice().executeShellCommand("-e emu finger touch 45146572");
```

My device won't react to it (I've tried on both classes and various threads). I believe this is caused by the fact executeShellCommand is running already inside shell. So it's like I've typed to terminal

```
Kamils-MacBook-Pro:~ F1sherKK$ adb shell
root@generic_x86_64:/ #
```

And I guess that's the problem, because google wants:

```
adb -e emu finger touch
```

not

```
adb shell -e emu finger touch
```

My knowledge about shell might be not enough maybe. I've looked through all [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html#IntentSpec) many times.

Do you have any idea how to call finger touch from shell?

Comment: I don't know how to help you, but just to clarify - you're saying you can trigger the fingerprint event from adb, but now you need to do it from an integration test rather than a shell?

Comment: Yes thats right. I want to do it from integration test, but the only way I can think of how to achieve it is to use exetuceShellCommand method.

Comment: @F1sher Did you find some solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to be using different format of password. It should be "aa11aa" which is LetterLetterNumberNumberLetterLetter.